# Product Attribute asking Values required

Tags: magento2

I have created product attribute and have given value for value required is "No". But in frontend, that product attribute is asking the value.

Below I have attached images of that. please help me to solve because it has been taking too many days.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: but in your screenshot default label says **BC_CM**, in your screenshot **Crown Molding** is the option of dropdown not the label of the dropdown. seems you have another attribute which name called Crown Molding, double check it.

Comment: @Hit's I have updated question. Just I have changed the label name in 'Mangae Label'.

Comment: did you try to run **php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush**?

Comment: @Hit's yes, I have run. But nothing happened.

Comment: can you also try this php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f ?

Comment: Can you please confirm that require value class not used on frontend?

Comment: @Hit's Should I run all those commands?

Comment: @user55548 I am not getting what you are saying?

Comment: Check view source of that dropdonw from firebug. Is there require class or requre:true for that drodown?

Comment: @user55548 yes, It showing required.   <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="option-label-bc_cm-202" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix"><select class="swatch-select bc_cm"><option value="0" option-id="0">Choose an Option...</option><option value="623" option-id="623">Crown Molding</option></select></div>

Comment: Because of this validation display. Have you add this using custom code ? require should not comes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84258/discussion-between-kevin-and-user55548).

Comment: @Hit's after i run the command what you said, the site is not working